# Asp.Net Web Api : Handling two get request with same signature

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

**Current situation**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckProfileStatus(int id)
    {
        //check profile status from third party
        return //profile status and HttpStatus;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage ProcessTheProfile(int profileId)
    {
        //check profile status from third party again, if status is "Good", do something
        return //someMessage and HttpStatus;
    }
```

Url to call `CheckProfileStatus` method

```
myUrl/api/Profile/123
```

Url to call `ProcessTheProfile` method

```
myUrl/api/Profile/?profileId=123
```

I hope the comments in the code makes the situation clear.

I don't really like the fact that I have two `HttpGet` methods with same signature in one controller (even though it works).

I don't know if it is best practice.

**Question:**

Should I extract these two methods in two seperate controllers, is it completely fine to have two HttpGet methods with same signature in one controller or is there better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Seems opinion based question. Can't you handle it in a single method?

Comment: You've tagged this question with `rest` so I'm assuming you're building a RESTful web service. A GET request to your profile endpoint `myUrl/api/Profile/123` should be returning the Profile with id=123. You should restructure your API for your two additional actions e.g. `GET myUrl/api/Profile/123/status` and  `PUT myUrl/api/Profile/123/process` (given your process method is changing the state of the object, this should not be a GET).

Comment: You can always declare a seperate route for the second method a la `[Route("Profile/{id:int}/Process")]` So the intent becomes clearer.

Comment: @Div It is opinion based I suppose

Comment: @ChrisPickford I like your suggestion. Maybe you can post it as answer, can help future question viewers. I will accept your suggestion

Comment: @Cybercop looks like Andrei's answer covers this pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is confusing to any client of the API.

You have 2 GET methods which are virtually identical. In fact most people prefer to add a route covering your first option which basically sets the profileId to the value after the forward slash.

Second, the expectation is that when you issue a GET against an entity with an ID, you get the representation of that entity. This is not what's happening here.

You need to decide which kind of API do you want. A generic one where stuff like this is fine :

`myUrl/api/profile/process/123` or `process/profile`, or whatever else makes sense to the API.

If your API is supposed to be **RESTful** ( which basically means you will have one method per HTTP verb and nothing more  ) then you need to add a new controller for *ProcessProfile* and then your url can look like this :

```
myUrl/api/ProcessProfile/123
```

None of these options is set in stone, they are just that, options. 
The comments to the OP thread give some good options as well, which should be considered.

Comment: if I have two method as Chris mentioned in comment, would the api still be RESTful?

Comment: does it matter? REST is just a convention nothing more. you are free to do whatever makes sense. the important question should be ... does it make sense to the clients of the API?